# Parallel Python: 4 threads have same speed as 2 threads

Tags: python, multithreading, python-2.7, parallel-python

I'm using [Parallel Python](http://www.parallelpython.com/) for executing a computation heavy code on multiple cores. 
I have an [i7-4600M](http://ark.intel.com/products/76349) processor, which has 2 cores and 4 threads.

The interesting thing is, the computation takes nearly the same time if I use 2 or 4 theads. I wrote a little example code, which demonstrates this phenomenon.

```
import itertools
import pp
import time

def cc(data, n):
    count = 0
    for A in data:
        for B in itertools.product((-1,0,1), repeat=n):
            inner_product = sum(a*b for a,b in zip(A,B))
            if inner_product == 0:
                count += 1
    return count

n = 9

for thread_count in (1, 2, 3, 4):
    print("Thread_count = {}".format(thread_count))
    ppservers = ()
    job_server = pp.Server(thread_count, ppservers=ppservers)

    datas = [[] for _ in range(thread_count)]
    for index, A in enumerate(itertools.product((0,1), repeat=n)):
        datas[index%thread_count].append(A)
    print("Data sizes: {}".format(map(len, datas)))

    time_start = time.time()
    jobs = [job_server.submit(cc,(data,n), (), ("itertools",)) for data in datas]
    result = sum(job() for job in jobs)
    time_end = time.time()
    print("Time = {}".format(time_end - time_start))
    print("Result = {}".format(result))
    print
```

Here's a short video of running the program and the cpu usage: https://www.screenr.com/1ULN When I use 2 threads, the cpu has 50% usage, if I use 4 threads, it uses 100%. But it's only slightly faster. Using 2 threads, I get a speedup of 1.8x, using 3 threads a speedup of 1.9x, and using 4 threads a speedup of 2x.

If the code is too fast, use `n = 10` or `n = 11`. But be careful, the complexity is `6^n`. So `n = 10` will take 6x as long as `n = 9`.

Comment: How intense is the work each thread is doing?  It may just be that the difference is negligible for smaller computations

Comment: Each job is working with 25% cpu usage for a few minutes.

Comment: You do know that even though your cores have multiple threads, Python's [Global Interpreter Lock](http://www.jeffknupp.com/blog/2012/03/31/pythons-hardest-problem/) prevents execution of multiple threads at the same time? So your two processors will execute each process of the program *serially* whether you use 2 threads (1 thread per core) or 4 threads (2 thread per core).

Comment: @RickTeachey Have a read through the [introduction page for Parallel Python](http://www.parallelpython.com/) that the question links to.

Answer (score 1):

2 cores and 4 threads means you have two hyperthreads on each core, which won't scale linearly, since they share resources and can get in each other's way, depending on the workload. Parallel Python uses processes and IPC behind the scenes. Each core is scheduling two distinct processes, so you're probably seeing cache thrashing (a core's cache is shared between hyperthreads).

Comment: Yeah, I know that it doesn't scale linearly. But I didn't expected it to be that bad. A 5% faster execution when using twice as much cpu usage is quite bad.

Answer (score 0):

I know this thread is a bit old but I figured some added data points might help. I ran this on a vm with 4 virtual-cpus (2.93Ghz X5670 xeon) and 8GB of ram allocated. The VM was hosted on Hyper-V and is running Python 2.7.8 on Ubuntu 14.10 64-bit, but my version of PP is the fork PPFT.

In the first run the number of threads was 4. In the second I modified the for loop to go to 8.

Output: http://pastebin.com/ByF7nbfm

Adding 4 more cores, and doubling the ram, same for loop, looping for 8:

Output: http://pastebin.com/irKGWMRy